# NSIS exe internal bytes and SHA26 differences

Tags: exe, nsis, sha

When I run the makeInstaller with no code change, the byte sizes are varying by 4-5 more or less and this affects the SHA26 on the generated exe causing integrity questions. Any thoughts here?

```
Processed 1 file, writing output (x86-ansi):

Output: "C:\Users\build\setup.exe"
Install: 4 pages (256 bytes), 2 sections (1 required) (4144 bytes), 681 instructions (19068 bytes), 322 strings (5999 bytes), 1 language table (302 bytes).
Uninstall: 3 pages (256 bytes), 1 section (2072 bytes), 312 instructions (8736 bytes), 152 strings (2665 bytes), 1 language table (286 bytes).
Datablock optimizer saved 861 bytes (~0.0%).

Using zlib compression.

EXE header size:               47104 / 37888 bytes
Install code:                   5696 / 28161 bytes
Install data:               37940628 / 96426788 bytes
Uninstall code+data:           49617 / 56047 bytes
CRC (0xD494AC91):                  4 / 4 bytes

Total size:                 38043049 / 96548888 bytes (39.4%)
```

Comment: NSIS version?...

Comment: NSIS version is 3.02.1

Comment: Try updating to 3.06.1

Comment: I did upgrade to 3.06.1.One thing noticed was we perform task:download NSIS.tar from local artifactory and then perform task:makeInstaller. So everytime task:download NSIS.tar is executed , makeInstaller produces file with different bytes. When I don't run task:download NSIS.tar and keep running only task:makeInstaller the bytes are same. From the download NSIS.tar I dont see any bytes difference. Unable to understand why makeInstaller would cause bytes difference?

Comment: I have no idea what makeInstaller is but if it compiles the NSIS source code it would have to set the source epoch variable.

Comment: My bad, makeInstaller invoke makeNSIS.exe. If we use the existing NSIS executable, the total bytes remains same. If we download NSIS executable and run makeNSIS.exe the total bytes differ from the above.

Answer (score 1):

Windows binaries aren't deterministic; the metadata contains time information regarding when the program was built. You can manually change the metadata using some hex editing and a bit of knowledge about how Windows likes its programs' headers, but if you want deterministic compilation you're gonna have to go out of your way to achieve that... Or more specifically the original developers would be the ones to do that, if you want to compare your SHA-256 with their version.